# Building a life table in R with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new to R and programming in general, and I'm struggling with a for-loop for building the lx function in a life table.

I have the age function x, the death function qx (the probability that someone aged exactly x will die before reaching age x+1), and the surviving function px = 1 - qx.

I want to write a function that returns a vector with all the lx values from first to last age in my table. The function is simple...
I've defined cohort = 1000000. The first age in my table is x = 5, so, considering x = 5...
l_(x) = cohort
And, from now on, l_(x+n) = l_(x+n-1)*p_(x+n-1)

I've searched about for-loops, and I can only get my code working for lx[1] and lx[2], and I get nothing for lx[n] if n > 2.

I wrote that function:

```
living_x <- function(px, cohort){
result <- vector("double", length(px))
l_x <- vector("double", length(px))
for (i in 1:length(px)){
    if (i == 1){
        l_x[i] = cohort
        }
    else l_x[i] = l_x[i-1]*px[i-1]
    result[i] = l_x
    print(result)
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get several outputs (more than length(px)) and "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)".
When I run warnings(), I get "In result[i] <- l_x : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" for every number.

Also, everything I try besides it give me different errors or only calculate lx for lx[1] and lx[2]. I know there's something really wrong with my code, but I still couldn't identify it. I'd be glad if someone could give me a hint to find out what to change.

Thank you!

Comment: The error "In result[i] <- l_x : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" is caused by trying to assign the vector `l_x` to a double value in the vector "result".  I am not sure the purpose of the variable `result`, thus either remove it or assign a single value to it: `result[i] <- l_x[i]`

Comment: btw, the package `babynames` includes a `lifetables` data frame with this data for each decade 1900 to 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it in a very simple way after thinking for some minutes more.

```
lx = c()
for (i in 2:length(px)){
lx[1] = 10**6
lx[i] = lx[i-1]*px[i-1]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` from the tidyverse packages, to use `px` to calculate `lx`. This can be done similarly in "Base R" using  `excerpt$lx = 100000 * cumprod(1 - lag(excerpt$qx))`.

`lx` is provided in the `babynames` package, so we can check our work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(babynames)

# Get excerpt with age, qx, and lx.
excerpt <- lifetables %>%
  filter(year == 2010, sex == "F") %>%
  select(x, qx_given = qx, lx_given = lx) 

excerpt 
    # A tibble: 120 x 3
       x qx_given lx_given
   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     0  0.00495   100000
 2     1  0.00035    99505
 3     2  0.00022    99471
 4     3  0.00016    99449
 5     4  0.00012    99433
 6     5  0.00011    99421
 7     6  0.00011    99410
 8     7  0.0001     99399
 9     8  0.0001     99389
10     9  0.00009    99379
# ... with 110 more rows
```

Using that data to estimate `lx_calc`:

```
est_lx <- excerpt %>%
  mutate(px = 1 - qx_given,
         cuml_px = cumprod(lag(px, default = 1)),
         lx_calc = cuml_px * 100000)
```

And finally, comparing visually the given `lx` with the one calculated based on `px`. They match exactly.

```
est_lx %>%
  gather(version, val, c(lx_given, lx_calc)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, val, color = version)) + geom_line()
```

[image]